# GCC dont push args even with -mpush-args -mno-accumulate-outgoing-args -mno-stack-arg-probe

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

The gcc dont push (assembly push) args even with:
`-mpush-args -mno-accumulate-outgoing-args -mno-stack-arg-probe`
But also there is no any error.

I tried it with 2 different versions of gcc.
What I need to do?

**EDIT:** I was trying to build a simple kernel

```
char read_char(void)
{
    return 'A'; //Doesn't read any char, just return 'A'.
}

void print(char letter,char row,char col){
   char*VGA=(char*) 0xB8000;
   VGA[(row*80+col)*2]=letter;
}

void __main(void){} \\ just for the linker (ld)
void main(void){
   print(read_char(),2,3);
}
```

But at assembly:

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDB0:
    .text
.LHOTB0:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  read_char
    .def    read_char;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   read_char
read_char:
    .seh_endprologue
    movl    $65, %eax
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDE0:
    .text
.LHOTE0:
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDB1:
    .text
.LHOTB1:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  print
    .def    print;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   print
print:
    .seh_endprologue
    movsbl  %dl, %edx
    movsbl  %r8b, %r8d
    leal    (%rdx,%rdx,4), %eax
    sall    $4, %eax
    addl    %eax, %r8d
    addl    %r8d, %r8d
    movslq  %r8d, %r8
    movb    %cl, 753664(%r8)
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDE1:
    .text
.LHOTE1:
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDB2:
    .text
.LHOTB2:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  __main
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   __main
__main:
    .seh_endprologue
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDE2:
    .text
.LHOTE2:
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDB3:
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
.LHOTB3:
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    subq    $40, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movb    $65, 753990
    addq    $40, %rsp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section    .text.unlikely,"x"
.LCOLDE3:
    .section    .text.startup,"x"
.LHOTE3:
    .ident  "GCC: (tdm64-1) 4.9.2"
```

NASM type assembly:

```
main:
push   ebp
mov    ebp,esp

call read_char ;at eax the return

mov    eax,0x3 ;3rd arg the eax override! (have not the return of read_char anymore!)
mov    edx,0x2 ;2nd arg
mov    ecx,eax ;1st arg but here the gcc thinks the eax contains the return but the eax have been overridden!
call   print

pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: Have you tried enabling optimisation (O1/O2) alongside those options?

Comment: No, what is this?

Comment: Well just try using `-O2 -mpush-args -mno-accumulate-outgoing-args -mno-stack-arg-probe`. A lot of GCC flags require enabled optimisations to be effective. No idea if it's the case here, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Didn't work but thanks a lot, this fixed some other problems such xor eax,eax instead mov eax,0

Comment: Do you have a minimal and reproducible example showcasing what you are trying to achieve and what is not working as expected? It would definitely help us out.

Comment: Is this being compiled on some version of Microsoft Windows GCC?

Comment: How can I detect that? The versions is 4.9.2 (Dev-cpp) and 5.1.0

Comment: So this is on Windows.That is TDM-GCC.What language or compiler did you use to compile the file that has read_char in it? It almost seems like you are trying to mix calling conventions, but it is unclear what the goal you have really is. By the way the video memory in real mode on the PC is at 0xb8000 not 0xb800 (or in segment:offset form 0xb800:0x0000)

Comment: actually there not exist read_char I have made a simple function in the same file `char read_char(void){return 'A';}` but the 'A' doesn't print! (for the 0xb8000 in my code I have this correct, I just forgot it here)

Comment: Each cell on the text mode display is 16-bits wide, not a single byte.

Comment: Yes I fexed, In my code I have also a color arg: VGA[(row*80+col)*2]=letter; VGA[(row*80+col)*2+1]=color; also the assembly isn't this I post the assembly have some more instructions but this is not necessary. If you want to post the real assembly ask it.

Comment: Use the `-S` option to have GCC generate assembly output and include that in your post. .For example `gcc -S -O2 -mpush-args -mno-accumulate-outgoing-args -mno-stack-arg-probe test.c` which will create an assembly file named `test.s`.

Comment: Also show your actual source code that generates the assembly output, use cut and paste to include in your post so you don't make any mistakes or omit anything. You should also show the full command with all the options you're using to compile your source code.

Comment: I add it into the post.

Comment: You gave us 64-bit code (not 32-bit code). If you are writing a 32-bit kernel  you need to use `-m32`. You'll probably also want to use `-freestanding -nostdinc`. I asume from the output you must have used some type of optimizations since this line pretty much does what you asked: `movb    $65, 753990` . That wrote the letter 'a' to address 0xB8146